# Using "partial" on a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, partial-classes

I am using a generic class called `ViewModelCollection<BaseViewModel>` which handles a lists of ViewModels and delivers standard `add()` and `delete()` commands.

Now I'm wondering if I can "extend" this class using the `partial` construct for a certain ViewModel, whose name is, say, `CarViewModel`.

Is something like this possible?

```
partial class ViewModelCollection<BaseViewModel>
{
    ... some command and list stuff ...
}

partial class ViewModelCollection<CarViewModel>
{
    ... special commands for car view model
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you can't, `partial` just splits the class definition over multiple files, the definition has to be the same. You need to derive from `ViewModelCollection<T>`:

```
public class ViewModelCollection<T> where T: BaseViewModel
{
   //methods
}

public class CarViewModelCollection : ViewModelCollection<CarVieModel>
{
  //specific methods
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hoped I wouldn't have to use derivation. The view model part in my application is generated so now I have to make some changes on the generators before going the derivation way. :-(

Answer (score 1):

`partial` is used only to split a class across multiple source files. The class definition itself must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Take the partial methods added and create an interface, you can then constrain the generic to use that interface and work off of those methods defined.